# Is there a directory or list of countries where chalav stam may be used?

Tags: chalav-yisrael-jewishmilk

Rav Moshe Feinstein, as I understand, permitted one to consume non-chalav Yisra'el products in U.S. (I assume Canada, as well.) I have heard from a few travelers that in most European countries, milk must be supervised (i.e., one may NOT consume chalav stam.)

I am assuming that there is a prohibition in most countries in the world, and that the list of permissible locations is the minority. Has someone published a (partial) list of places where one may consume chalav stam?